# Springboot set config to use ANT_PATH_MATCHER

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui

I'm using `Swagger-ui 3.0.0` with `Springboot 2.7.15`, since swagger ui 3.0 uses ant path matcher but Springboot 2.7.15 by default doesn't use so I need to set `#spring.mvc.pathmath.matching-strategy = ANT_PATH_MATCHER` in my `application.properties`

Just want to know if there's any way to set it programtically. I know `@EnableWebMvc` can enable ant path matcher but it also brings in other configs so I don't like to do it.

I tried `extends WebMvcConfigurer` and

```
@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setPathMatcher(new AntPathMatcher());
}
```

it doens't work.

Answer (score 0):

Try insert
`System.setProperty("spring.mvc.pathmatch.matching-strategy", "ant_path_matcher");`
in class, annotated as @SpringBootApplication, in main function before all other code.
I can't modify application.properties on production servers and use this method.